# Macro substituting a constant number in GAS

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu, gnu-assembler

What't wrong with that macro on X86 GNU Assembly? It says the symbol S is undefined during linking.

```
.macro S size=40
\size
.endm
```

I'm using it like

```
mov %eax, S
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Macros are used to create templates for code you frequently use, not to input a constant number. As such, I do not believe the assembler does macro expansion within an expression. Since you simply want a number, you could use `.set` to define a constant.

```
.set S, 40
mov %eax, S
```

Also, in case you usually use intel syntax, make sure you realize what this code is doing: It currently stores the value of eax in memory at the address 0x28. If you want to put the number 40 in eax, you need to reverse the operands and use a dollar sign in front of S.

```
mov $S, %eax
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also directly assign symbols with the equals sign `=`:

```
S = 40
```

which the GNU as manual says is equivalent to using `.set` https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.19/as/Setting-Symbols.html#Setting-Symbols

> A symbol can be given an arbitrary value by writing a symbol, followed by an equals sign `=', followed by an expression (see Expressions). This is equivalent to using the .set directive. See .set. In the same way, using a double equals sign`='`=' here represents an equivalent of the .eqv directive. See .eqv.

`.equ` is yet another synonym...

```
 .equ S, 40
```

One typical use case of such constants, is to calculate the length of static strings, e.g. the Linux x86_64 hello world can be written as:

hello_world.S

```
    .data
hello_world:
    .ascii "hello world\n"
    hello_world_len = . - hello_world
.text
.global _start
_start:
    /* write */
    mov $1, %rax
    mov $1, %rdi
    mov $hello_world, %rsi
    mov $hello_world_len, %rdx
    syscall

    /* exit */
    mov $60, %rax
    mov $0, %rdi
    syscall
```

which you can compile and run wth:

```
as -o hello_world.o hello_world.S
ld -o hello_world.out hello_world.o
./hello_world.out
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/9dccafe00d9b0affa8847836a71ebb4c37be7090/userland/arch/x86_64/freestanding/linux/hello.S).

`%rdx` will then contain the length of the string to be written.

The `$` is required just like for any regular address label, otherwise you would be trying to access that memory address instead of moving an immediate.

Comment: does it matter at all in what section the symbol goes in? For example, in the `.data` or `.rodata` section?

Comment: @David542 the constructs discussed in this answer should not affect data vs rodata. About the general case, I'm not entirely sure of the application of rodata, it might be only a security thing of trying to keep as much memory non modified as possible to make it harder to inject code.